# JdbcTemplate throwing exception during concurrent execution

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, completable-future

I am trying to execute Jdbctemplate queries in parallel using completableFuture. Queries would run perfectly for first few times but after sometime spring fails to create bean if I execute queries. I have to restart program to make it work again.

Here's my code -

```
List<CompletableFuture<JSONObject>> completableFutureList = new ArrayList<>();

for(String query : queryList){
  CompletableFuture<JSONObject> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
   .supplyAsync(() -> jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query))
   .thenApply(data -> createJson(data));

 completableFutureList.add(completableFuture);
}

//collecting all the jsonObjects and putting in JSONArray tableList
CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture
.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0])).thenAccept(justVoid -> {

    for (CompletableFuture<JSONObject> a : completableFutureList) {
         JSONObject b = a.join();
         tableList.put(b);
    }
});

try {
      combinedFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e || ExecutionException e) {
    //catch exception
     }
```

The exception I'm getting is -

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties': Could not bind properties to 'DataSourceProperties' : prefix=spring.datasource, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@d7d7ea8 has been closed already